# $.post is only submitting first row of results in while loo jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have searched in many threads but can't seem to find the answer. I have a form that is being submitted based on a while loop. I have a jquery system which works but only submits the first result regardless of which row  I have chosen to delete. I tried changing all the ID's to classes but that still doesn't work. I don't want to have to reload the page.

This is my code:

```
 <script>

    function DeleteHomework() {

    var studentid = $(".studentid").val();
    var <?php echo $classsubjects; ?> = $(".<?php echo $classsubjects; ?>").val();
    var datesent = $(".datesent").val();
    $.post("deletehomework.php", { studentid: studentid, datesent: datesent, <?php echo "$classsubjects: $classsubjects,"; ?> },
    function(data) {
     $('#deletehomeworkresult').html(data);
    });
}

  </script>      


<form>
        <?php

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($gethomeworkdata)) {
        $datehomeworksent = $row['timestamp'];
        $datehomeworksent123 = $row['timestamp'];
        $datehomeworksent = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($datehomeworksent));
        $homeworksubject = $row[$classsubjects];
        $javadate = str_replace('-', '', $datehomeworksent);

        ?>
         <tr><input type="text" hidden value="<?php echo $studentid; ?>" name="studentid" class="studentid"><input type="text" hidden value="<?php echo $datehomeworksent123; ?>" name="datesent" class="datesent">
            <td><?php echo $datehomeworksent; ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control <?php echo $classsubjects; ?>" value="<?php echo $homeworksubject; ?>" name="<?php echo $classsubjects; ?>" id="<?php echo $classsubjects; ?>"></td>
            <td>
                            <button type="button" rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-success" onclick="EditHomework();">
                              <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                </button>
                            <button type="button" rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="DeleteHomework();">
                              <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                </button>
                            </td>


        </tr>
        <?php
    }?> </form>
```

Would appreciate any help knowing where i've gone wrong.

Comment: Why is quite straightforward.... `val()` will always get the value of the *first matching element* when you do `var someValue = $(selector).val()`. You have no way using your current inline `onclick` to isolate row instances and to look for the associated elements within that row instance. Your function takes in no arguments and therefore does the same thing regardless of which specific button instance is clicked

Comment: So how would I go around changing this to make it work?

Comment: For starters I would change `onclick` to using jquery since you already are using it and within a click handler `this` is the element the event occured on . From `this` you can do things like `var $row = $(this).closest('tr'); var studentid  = $row.find(".studentid").val()/` which will give you the  id value from within this specific row where you clicked the button